# sql query for filteringaccording to experience

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

i have this table

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HRCandidateProject](
[ProjectId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[orgid] [int] NULL,
[uid] [int] NULL,
[CandidateId] [bigint] NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ProjectName] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
[SkillSet] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Role] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Client] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ProjectDiscription] [varchar](500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[TotalExperience][int]
      CONSTRAINT [PK_HRCandidateProject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
[ProjectId] ASC
    )WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

in a drop down list i have values for total experience 1-2 years, 2-4, years 4-7 years, more than 7 years

i want to write a query that will display data if I select 1-2 years in dropdownlist it must display only those candidates that have exoerience between 1 to 2 years

Comment: I am not quite sure what your question is here??? What are the physical values you have in SkillSet ?? and what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to sort with experience also along with skill set

Comment: what is relation between skillset and total experience? you put where on the skillset,why? this where clause filter your data for a specific skillset and there is no need to sort it because it returns just a specific skill set

Comment: This is filtering, not sorting. You will use a where clause like what you have suggested, but you will probably want to use DropDownList1.Selectedvalue instead.

Comment: it is also implemented with a huge SQL injection hole

Answer (score 1):

Define your dropdown list values by setting a map as such:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Experience" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1-2 Years</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2-4 Years</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">4-7 Years</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">More than 7 Years</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In your query, check for each of these values in an OR branch and if the value matches the selected, filter based on experience:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    HRCandidateProject
WHERE   
    (
        @SelectedExperience = 1
        AND TotalExperience BETWEEN 1 AND 2
    )
    OR  (
        @SelectedExperience = 2
        AND TotalExperience BETWEEN 2 AND 4
    )
    OR  (
        @SelectedExperience = 3
        AND TotalExperience BETWEEN 4 AND 7
    )
    OR  (
        @SelectedExperience = 4
        AND TotalExperience > 7
    )
```

A couple things to note:

- You should put this in a stored procedure or execute it inline with the parameter, don't concatenate the selected value from the dropdown list into the query. A quick Google search and you should find how to parameterize your query.
- Based on the parameters of your question, the values returned will overlap. A candidate with 2 years of experience will show up in both the first and second result sets, etc. You should be able to tweak this criteria to prevent that if that is an undesired behavior.
- Don't go to production with SELECT *, type out all your column names.